# Hierarchical deadlocking (with dependencies), ...or: how do I get my "wait"s, "notify"s, and design right?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, wait, notify

```
// multiple server instances (replicas), coordinated using MsgCoordinationService
public class Server {

    ConcurrentHashMap<TxID,Future<Msg>> local_registry = new ...
    MsgCoordinationService coordination_service = new .. 

    ...

    // Socket instance to communicate with a client...
    public void accept(Socket s) {
        new Thread(new Worker(s)).start();
    }

    // propose msg to coordination service, register demand to respond to client in local registry
    public Future<Msg> register(Msg m) {
        FutureMsg f = new MsgFuture(); // Future handle w. reference to an empty Msg object [= response]
        TxID uniqueID = coordination_service.propose(s); // transaction ID
        local_registry.add(uniqueID, f);
        return f;
    }

    // called by coordination service, guaranteeing a global order on msg deliveries
    public synchronized void deliver(TxID id, Msg m) {
        ... process Msg object [request]
        ... if local_registry.contains(id), 'compile' response
            (using the Msg object from FutureMsg f, f.get() - f.isDone() when a certain Msg flag has been set)

        ___ now:
        ... notify waiting 'Worker' threads to check whether their 'Future' object isDone()
    }

    private class Worker implements Runnable {
        ...
        public void run() {
            ...
            Future<Msg> f = Server.this.register(request); // obtained through Socket s

            while(!f.isDone())
                wait();

            response = f.get();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I'm implementing a replicated service [multiple servers, clients communicate w. a single server instance, create/update/delete operations will be distributed by means of a coordination service that guarantees a global order on message deliveries].

Once a client establishes a new connection to a server instance, all communication is channeled through a dedicated `Worker` instance [that processes read requests locally, and broadcasts C/U/D operations using `Server.this.register(...)`].

`register` itself basically records requests for future local processing/reply - and forwards a `Msg` object to the coordination service.

The service redelivers the `Msg` object via `deliver`, ...and after processing the encapsulated task, the `Worker` instance which originally received the client request shall be notified to hand over the corresponding response.

For certain reasons, my design seems to be broken... - w/o `synchronized(this)` [in `Worker#run()`], `wait()` won't wait; with `synchronized(this)`, a `notifyAll()` in `Server#deliver(...)` won't release the lock on the "blocked" `Worker` instance.

Long story short: as it turns out, I need you help... either (a): to understand the very basics of `wait/notify/notifyAll` or (b): to improve my design ...or (c): (a) *and* (b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thread calling `wait/notify` requires the lock on the object on which these methods are called, otherwise you will get an exception. In the general form, assuming an arbitrary object:

```
final Object obj = new Object();
...

synchronized(obj) {
    while(/* condition */) {
       obj.wait();
    }
}
```

The reason why your `wait` is not being released by the `notify` is that you are doing a `this.wait()` inside a different object than the one where you are calling `notify`, hence they are not paired. You need to use the same instance for both calls. You are doing `this.wait()` inside an instance of `Worker` and doing `this.notifyAll()` inside an instance of `Server`, so `this` does not refer to the same object.

You should create a single synchronization object visible across classes and threads and synchronize on that one.